# How to create a PIVOT using two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have two tables:

Table1:

```
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     Category  |  Name  |  Goal  |  WK40  |  WK41  |  WK42  |  WK43  |  WK44  |  WK 45 |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     Data      |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Table2:

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
|  W1   |   W2   |   W3   |   W4   |   W5   |   W6  |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| WK40  |  WK41  |  WK42  |  WK43  |  WK44  |  WK45 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```

In Table 1, the WK40, WK41 etc. column names are dynamic (i.e., these column names change every week depending on the current week of the year & then shows the last 6 weeks). Table 1 has all the required data.

In Table 2, the column names are W1, W2, ...W6 and the column name here is static. But the data in each column (WK40, WK41....) changes every week based on the current week.

I want to create a table like this:

```
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
|     Category  |  Name  |  Goal  |   W1   |   W2   |   W3   |   W4   |   W5   |   W6    |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
|     Data      |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data  |  Data   |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```

I've never used PIVOT before so need help creating one for this. Thanks.

Comment: it will help us to understand your situation better if you can add some realistic sample data and the expected result. `Data` everywhere doesn't help much

Comment: I would strongly suggest normalising your data rather than finding a quick-fix solution to this particular problem. If you normalise your data, you at least have the option of pivoting whichever way you want after it without having to figure out a silly work-around to ever-changing column names.

Comment: I agree with ZLK. Normalization makes work like this so much simpler, and it keeps the solution dynamically able to add new columns on its own. Much easier than having to go back to an old solution to make it able to handle new data needs.